# rosdep install with metapackage

Tags: rosdep, ros-hydro, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I created a metapackage wrapping some of our own ros packages by declaring a run_depend on them. When I then run `rosdep check my_metapackage` everything is fine despite some system requirements of those run_depend packages are not met.

I know I could change the run_depend to build_depend, but then I get a warning for doing so. So ... I want to install the system-dependencies of a whole 'stack' aka metapackage with one command like `rosdep install my_metapackage` and not running the rosdep install for every single package ... is that possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98306/rosdep-install-with-metapackage/) by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't use a metapackage to do that, if you have all of the packages cloned locally you can do this:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths ./path/to/packages --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --simulate
```

That line will find all of the catkin packages in that path, and attempt to install their dependencies from your package manager, ignoring dependencies which can be found checked out locally from source. (also it just simulates its actions, remove the `--simulate` to actually do it).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3